# How do I make the decrypt text show up as just a single line instead of a new line for each letter?

Tags: python, string, encryption, concatenation

We had a class project where we had to create our own cipher and hashing algorithms.  I chose to use an Xor cipher in python and it works, except that when I print the Decrypted text it prints a new line for each letter or space.
so it looks like this:

```
*****Decrypt*****

Enter the encrypted message here: 030a090e450d030c0a4b1216190e0a

Enter the provided key: key

Decrypted Text:  h

Decrypted Text:  ho

Decrypted Text:  hop

Decrypted Text:  hope

Decrypted Text:  hope 

Decrypted Text:  hope t

Decrypted Text:  hope th

Decrypted Text:  hope thi

Decrypted Text:  hope this

Decrypted Text:  hope this 

Decrypted Text:  hope this w

Decrypted Text:  hope this wo

Decrypted Text:  hope this wor

Decrypted Text:  hope this work

Decrypted Text:  hope this works
```

I only want the last line that appears as "Decrypted Text:  hope this works."

Here's the code.

````
def encrypt():
    msg = input("Type your message here: ")
    key = input("Enter your desired key: ")

    encrypt_hex = ""
    key_itr = 0
    for i in range(len(msg)):
        temp = ord(msg[i]) ^ ord(key[key_itr])
        encrypt_hex += hex(temp) [2:].zfill(2)
        key_itr += 1
        if key_itr >= len(key):
            key_itr = 0

    print("Encrypted Text:  {}\n".format(encrypt_hex))

    main()

def decrypt():
    msg = input("Enter the encrypted message here: ")
    key = input("Enter the provided key: ")

    hex_to_text = ""
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
        hex_to_text += bytes.fromhex(msg[i:i+2]).decode('utf-8')

        decrypt_text = ""
        key_itr = 0
        for i in range(len(hex_to_text)):
            temp = ord(hex_to_text[i]) ^ ord(key[key_itr])
            decrypt_text += chr(temp)
            key_itr += 1
            if key_itr >= len(key):
                key_itr = 0
        print("Decrypted Text:  {}\n".format(decrypt_text))

    main()

def hash():
    import hashlib
    msg1 = input("Enter your text here:  ")
    msg1_hash = hashlib.sha512(msg1.encode())
    print("Here's the hash value for this text: {}\n".format(msg1_hash.hexdigest()))

    main()

def check():
    import hashlib
    msg_check = input("Enter hash here: ")
    new_msg = input("Enter text to check here:  ")

    new_msg_hash = hashlib.sha512(new_msg.encode())
    if msg_check == new_msg_hash.hexdigest():
        print("The hasehes match text is unaltered.\n")
    else:
        print("The hashes don't match the text has been altered.\n")

    main()

def main():
    choice = int(input("1:  Encrypt String\n2:  Decrypt String\n3:  Hash SHA512\n4:  Check Hash SHA512\nSelect(1,2,3,4):    "))
    if choice == 1:
        print("*****Encrypt*****")
        encrypt()
    elif choice == 2:
        print("*****Decrypt*****")
        decrypt()
    elif choice == 3:
        print("*****Hash SHA512*****")
        hash()
    elif choice == 4:
        print ("*****Hash Check SHA512*****")
        check()
    else:
        print("This is not a valid selection, please chose 1 or 2.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```
````

Comment: Initialize the `decrypt_text` variable outside the loop, and print after the loop instead of once per iteration. Also, put main in some sort of loop instead of recursively calling it at the end of each function. Otherwise you will eventually get a stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
 def decrypt():
    msg = input("Enter the encrypted message here: ")
    key = input("Enter the provided key: ")

    # variable initiation moved to before loop
    decrypt_text = ""
    hex_to_text = ""
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
        hex_to_text += bytes.fromhex(msg[i:i+2]).decode('utf-8')

    key_itr = 0
    # For loop moved out of the previous for loop
    for i in range(len(hex_to_text)):
        temp = ord(hex_to_text[i]) ^ ord(key[key_itr])
        decrypt_text += chr(temp)
        key_itr += 1
        if key_itr >= len(key):
            key_itr = 0
    # print statement moved to after loop
    print("Decrypted Text:  {}\n".format(decrypt_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

`def decrypt():
    msg = input("Enter the encrypted message here: ")
    key = input("Enter the provided key: ")

```
decrypt_text = ""
hex_to_text = ""
for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
    hex_to_text += bytes.fromhex(msg[i:i+2]).decode('utf-8')

    decrypt_text = ""
    key_itr = 0
    for i in range(len(hex_to_text)):
        temp = ord(hex_to_text[i]) ^ ord(key[key_itr])
        decrypt_text += chr(temp)
        key_itr += 1
        if key_itr >= len(key):
            key_itr = 0
print("Decrypted Text:  {}\n".format(decrypt_text))`
```